# How to extract and simplify lines using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, lines, feature-extraction

I have skeletonized image. How can I extract and simplify lines like on right image using OpenCV?

[image: Example]

Thank you.

**Update**

I have got nodes of skeleton.

[image: Skeleton nodes]

For now I need to join points if they are on the same line. How can I do it?

[image: Joined points]

And after that simplify this path. I think I know how do it, but if you have any idea, please, give me advice.

[image: Simplify path]

Comment: I hardly understand how you filter (logically not programmatically) the other lines. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Please, see update. Sorry, my English isn't perfect.

Comment: @NicolaPezzotti I forgot to notify you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to create a **graph** given the knots of your skeleton image. Vertices of your graph will correspond to the knot set.

I suggest you this algorithm to extract the edges of the graph:

For each knot use an 8-neighborhood (8N) to visit all the pixel neir the knot. Put all the skeleton pixel in a queue and continue untill you find a knot. Once the queue is empty you'll have all the edges for the given knot